# what means "ilegal use of registers"?

Tags: assembly, ollydbg, disassemblers, decompile, immunity-debugger

I read pe program using a Pe Reader to view all sections, the .text section starts is "`0x0001000`":

What is in the pe program reader:

[image: PE READER PROGRAM]

And is this what i see on the debugguer :

[image: DEBUGGER]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html), `0xFF` is a “jump far indirect” opcode and this version of jump requires operand to be a memory address.

While using this type of jump, you cannot use register as an operand and hence the error message you see.

And I don’t think the snippet you provided contains the actual code - it rather looks like data, though OllyDbg still tries to disassemble it.

You will find the code at offset `0x1000` relative to the image base which will likely be `0x400000` in case of exe and `0x10000000` in case of dll.